# List items with same height

Tags: html, css

I have created a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pQZ8f/

I want to have both the list items to be of same height without setting height manually. I want it to auto grow. I don't want to use javascript. Can it done be through css?

Comment: You mean, without setting a fixed height?

Comment: Yes without setting a fixed height. Sorry I missed that in question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ahh, yee old same height column problem.

One solution is to fart around with bottom margin / padding.

Works in IE7+ (might even work using ie6, I don't have it installed)

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
li {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background: red;
    padding-bottom: 10000px;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
}
li + li {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pQZ8f/593/)**

Comment: They are not the same height...this illusion most probably disappoints people who seek a real same-height solution.

Comment: @vsync Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: I mean is your answer doesn't give the elements the same height. I'm not trying to be a d*ck or anything, just saying this answer has nothing to do with the question beside a trick from 8 years ago to make them have the same background color.. in 99% of the cases, people need them to BE same height, like the title and question suggests.

Comment: @vsync that's correct, I read this question as "How can I make two columns look like they're the same height", for this specific problem is there are difference between having the same height, and just visibly having the same height?  Of course there's quite a few different ways to solve it, but this solution solves the problem without adding any additional markup, nor relying on javascript, while still retaining good browser compatibility.  While semantically they're not the same height, pragmatically it solves the problem.

Answer (score 24):

It seems you're looking for a tabular layout, so maybe the best bet would be to use a `<table>` instead of floating `<li>` elements.

That said, you can also specify tabular styles on your elements:

```
ul {
    display: table-row;
}

li {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

This should work on most modern browsers. You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pQZ8f/2/).

Comment: I would use table in that case.

Comment: @emphaticsunshine, if your content is inherently tabular, you should. Tables have been abused for layout in the past, still there is no shame in using them when you need them.

Comment: It looks like a tabular structure in fiddle but actually it has lot of data inside cells and I don't like using tabular structure when there is lot of different content in cells.

Comment: Fiddle was only a POC but not actual data or design.

Comment: @emphaticsunshine, then, at this level of complexity, you probably should consider scripting. CSS does have limitations, and there are now many Javascript libraries around that could solve your problem quite efficiently. I do not know the full requirements of your project, but I think it would be at least worth a try.

Comment: Yes, I can use js but was trying to know if it can be done through css only. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: 2019, This code is still working but the issue is, If there are more then 6-7 li tag then all the li will display in one line... is there any other way like display 4 li in one line and rest of display below?

Answer (score 9):

It's 2018, and we have display: flex, with 97.66% browser support (https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

With flexbox, all you need to do is:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
}

li{
 width:100px;
 border: 1px solid black;   
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pQZ8f/1076/

Answer (score 3):

You can use: **display: inline-table** on your LI elements

```
li {
    width:100px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-table
}
```

here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQZ8f/823/)

Comment: Using `display: inline-table;` on the `li` element worked for me as my parent `ul` element was using `columns: 2;`. 

I think this is one of best, easiest solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul 
{
  display: table;
}

li
{
  display:table-cell;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on *why* you want them the same height: what overall effect are you trying to achieve?

One option: If you're simply trying to match a background or something, you can put the background on the `<ul>` instead of the `<li>`'s and the `<ul>` will expand automatically to whatever the max height is of its child elements.

Further, if you're trying to make them the same height so you can align the *bottom* of the text, you can combine `display: inline-block` instead of `float`, and `horizontal-align: bottom;`. The result in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQZ8f/15/) gets you something that at least *looks* like the `<li>`'s are the same height, but won't work for borders.

Comment: I need a separation border. So if I give border to one of the list item and it is a shorter one, the separation won't reach bottom

Comment: In that case, I think you'll definitely want to go with Matthew's or Frédéric Hamidi's suggestions, which are far more sophisticated than mine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery.matchHeight.js library for this purpose. Adding **class ="frame-height"** to all **li** elements, make all **li** elements the same height as the highest **li** element.

Answer (score 0):

List is set as table and it will contain table properties.
for list item when you set table-cell they will get table cell properties and by default all table cells will get same height.

```
<!--SCSS-->
.list {
     display: table;

    .list-item {
       display: table-cell;
    }
}



<!--html-->
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list-iteam">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <p>Details in text</p>
    </li>
    <li class="list-iteam">
        <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    </li>
    <li class="list-iteam">
        <h1>Heading 2</h1>
        <p>this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text this is text </p>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and post some explanation to your code. Code-only answers are discouraged.