# How to make an <a> 100% height of <li>?

Tags: css

```css
ul {
    display: table-row;
}
    
li {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
}

a {
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        Test  
        Test
        Test
        Test            
    </li>
</ul>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12325056/65387) explains how to make `<li>`s the same height, but now how can I make an `<a>` fill the entire height of its `li` (without using a fixed height)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are dealing with tables, and table height values are used as a minimal value when computing table and table-cell heights.

The easiest fix is to provide a height value to the CSS table parent block.
First, to the `ul`, apply `display: table` instead of table-row, and then specify `height: 1px` and any non-zero value will work. Remember to zero out margins and padding (due to the ul default settings).

Make sure that the CSS table-cell element has `height: 100%`, and then the `a` element will take on the height (since it is displayed as a block).

**Note:** If you set the top level height to 100%, this will work in Chrome but fail in IE.

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  height: 1px; /* any small value will work */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}
a {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Test Test Test
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works in FF, not in Chrome.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight I fixed the solution so it now works in FF, Chrome and IE. Thank you for your help in testing and checking.

Comment: First one here to work in all 3 major ones for me. +1

Answer (score 7):

Use `inline-block` rather than `block`. You'll now need to set `width`, as well.

```css
ul {
  display: table-row;
  height: 0;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Test Test Test
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Included tweaks from the FF-specific solution. For me, this now works in both FF and Chrome.

Comment: Wow - who would have thought the a would be inline-block and not block.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the following work ...

```
a {
    height: 100px;
}
```

... the parent must have a non auto height. For example,

```
li {
    height: 100%;
}
```

... so the same for the grandad:

```
ul {
    height: 0;
}
```

Using `height: 0` may seem a bit weird. But note that, since the `ul` is a table-row, that's only a minimum height.

```css
ul {
  display: table-row;
  height: 0;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}
a {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Test Test Test
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, it seems Chrome may require the `ul` to be a table instead of a table-row.

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}
a {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    Test Test Test Test
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works in FF, for those concerned about the answer @PaulRoub provided

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight But it doesn't work in Chrome now!

Comment: @Mark Doh! Why can't browsers all just play nice with one set of CSS?

Comment: @KheemaPandey, it does not on 42.0.2311.90 m. It looks the same as OP.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Funny, it doesn't work in my copy of Chrome 42.

Comment: @KheemaPandey I'm on Chrome 41 on Linux. It appears to be the latest stable release at the moment.