# How to make an <a> with padding 100% height of <li>.table-cell?

Tags: html, css

This question is like this: [How to make an <a> 100% height of <li>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780799/how-to-make-an-a-100-height-of-li) , except that this time `a` elements need vertical padding. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/7j60xgbg/ is the fiddle. Setting `height: 100%;` on `a` does not work, because it makes it stretching out below of the list.

How to make all `a` elements in this fiddle fill the available height *and* retain their padding?

Comment: Does setting `a{ height: 100%}` not work?

Comment: Setting `height: 100%;` on `a` does not work in Iceweasel. So neither in FF, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box-sizing : border-box` is your friend here:

```
a {
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    color: black;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7j60xgbg/3/

Answer (score 0):

Setting `a { height: 100% }` should work:

```css
ul {
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
    height: 1em;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    border: thin solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}

a {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    color: black;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">1st item</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">2nd item</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Some veeeeeeeeeeeeery long menu item, with a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text.... a lot of text....</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">3rd</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It doesn't in Iceweasel.

Answer (score 0):

In css of `a` add `display:inline-block;height:100%;vertical-algin:top or middile`

```
a{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    color: black;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you want something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/7j60xgbg/4/

```
li { 
  display: table 
}

a {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

The trick is to set a `display: table` for the `<li>` and `display: table-cell` with `vertical-align: middle` for the anchor, though you have to set a **fixed height** for the list.

Comment: Unfortunately this menu content is dynamic... setting fixed height for the list is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Same as your code but add height:100% into a tag.

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
    height: 1em;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    border: thin solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}

a {
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    color: black;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    height:100%;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following css will work for you. give `height:100%` and change padding to  `padding: 0 1em;`

```
a {
    background-color: green;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
```

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/7j60xgbg/5/)